# Can you clarify this JavaScript variable hoisting behavior?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

#### Case1:

```
var text = 'outside';
function logIt(){
    console.log(text);
    text ='inside';
}
logIt(); //prints outside. why?
```

I thought the `text` inside the function `logIt()` will be hoisted to the top of the function and will print `undefined`?

#### Case2:

```
var text = 'outside';
function logIt(){
    console.log(text);
    var text ='inside';
}
logIt(); //prints undefined
```

This one prints `undefined` as expected. Could someone explain why in `case1` we getting the value `outside`?

Comment: Variables declared outside a function are global and can be used inside a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the variable **declaration** that's getting hoisted, not the assignment.

In the first function you're only overriding the value of `text` *after* the call to `console.log`, but no other `text` is being introduced to the local scope of the function.

In the second case, you *are* introducing a new `text` variable that is local (and initialized to `undefined`, as expected), and due to variable hoisting, the actual `var text` line is interpreted *before* the call to `console.log`, hence the `undefined`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Answer (score 2):

Because of hoisting the inner variable `text` is moved to the beginning of the function. But only it's name portion:

```
var text = 'outside';
function logIt(){
    var text;
    console.log(text);
    text ='inside';
}
logIt(); //prints undefined
```

Case 1 logs "outside", because `text` is a variable in the surrounding scope of `logIt` and hence accessible within `logIt`. You reassign `text` lexically after the `console.log` call. So this reassingment isn't considered.

Comment: @Wild hm, maybe you assume that `text ='inside';` is hoisted too. Please notice that only variable `var x = "inside";` and function declarations `function f() {}` are hoisted.

Answer (score 1):

Hoisting: You can understand it as Entire function body is taken at the top of the script along with variables which
have a value of undefined (if using them before assignment is done)

Now Case1:

At the time when you are calling the function and the console.log executes the value of text is still "outside"

And after console log it changes value to "inside"

If you write console.log immediately after calling logIt(), it will display "inside" then.

```
var text = 'outside';
function logIt(){
    console.log(text);
    text ='inside';
}
logIt(); //prints outside. why?
```

Case 2: In this case you are making a new var inside the function logIt which will then be hoisted as
var text = undefined (as you are using it before assignment)

```
var text = 'outside';
function logIt(){
    console.log(text);
    var text ='inside';
}
logIt(); //prints undefined
```

Try printing console.log(text) after calling function this time. It will print "outside in this case as global scope has no effect because of logIt function in this case"