# In JavaScript, why does this global variable become undefined in my function?

Tags: javascript

```js
var x = 3;
function func(randomize) {
    if (randomize) {
        var x = Math.random();
        return x;
    }
    return x;
}
console.log(func(false));
```

As you can see from above code, `if statement never be true` but the `x` value is `undefined`, i would like to understand how variable declaration works in javascript. Any references also be helpful.
**Update:**
Can anybody explain why variable was re-declared to undefined and how it is related to hoisting in javascript

Comment: Classic hoisting

Comment: I think the -3 is excessive. It has a MCVE, and while it may be obvious to those fluent in JS, it's not a terrible question.

Comment: I know little about hosting in javascript, but the variable `x` is defined outside the function and we are not returning `function reference`

Comment: Returning function references doesn't have anything to do with hoisting. If you define `x` inside the function with `var`, it becomes a local variable everywhere inside the function, even if the definition was inside an if block that was never executed.

Comment: the part i get confused how variable was `redeclared` as `if statement was not true`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually, this question is subtly different than the one to which you linked.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Not in any meaningful way. But by all means, find the duplicate adding the `if` in there -- I guarantee you there is one. Probably several.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: **Completely** agree. I wouldn't vote the question up, but I certainly wouldn't downvote it. Just close, perhaps comment to point to the specific way in which the linked question is relevant.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i was actually reading a [book](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_core-features.html#sec_from-var-to-const) and i googled before i post the question but could not find any solutions so i posted question here

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This site is extra brutal lately. Wrote up what I thought was a great question yesterday, and it got downvoted within half a minute of posting (it's at +5 now, so it obviously wasn't a bad question). And like 10 minutes ago I saw a 20 second old question with a downvote, when it really wasn't a terrible question. I think people need to be as selective with their downvotes as they are with their upvotes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: That **would** be a great improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `func` is in essence:

```
function func(randomize) {
    var x;
    if (randomize) {
        x = Math.random();
        return x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Variables in JavaScript have function scope, not block scope with which you might be familiar from other languages. This results in the [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) behavior you observe:

> What does happen is that ***variable and function declarations are put into memory during the compile phase***, but stays exactly where you typed it in your coding.
>
> ...
>
> ***JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.***  (*emphases mine*)

That is, even though inside `func` you declare `x` in the `if` block, during compile time its declaration is moved to function level where it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `x` in global scope. However, it is only *initialized* if the argument to `func` is `true` which leads to the behavior you observe.

See also [`let`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011):

```js
"use strict";
var x = 3;
function func(randomize) {
    if (randomize) {
        let x = Math.random();
        return x;
    }
    return x;
}
console.log(func(false));
console.log(func(true));
```

Comment: We don't need **yet another** answer to this question.

Comment: @Sinan unur  He is talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508842/javascript-variable-hoisting-confusion)

Comment: @JinsPeter Well, if [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508842/javascript-variable-hoisting-confusion) is to be the *canonical answer* to all hoisting questions, then you or T.J. might want to put some effort into improving its presentation.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: There are dozens -- hundreds -- of dupetargets for this, I wouldn't be surprised if there were better ones. By all means go and look, and flag up any others you think are relevant, we can include them. And of course, if you think that question's answers are lacking post an answer there.

Comment: @Kinduser: I would suggest finding the earlier example of this pattern (again, it's there) and posting the answer there if it doesn't just duplicate what's already been said there. Posting an answer on a question closed half an hour earlier is clearly not cool.

Comment: Thanks @SinanÜnür for taking your time and addressing important point `JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations`. that's what confused me, that's not told most of the times when they answer any question about hoisting

Answer (score -2):

You define a new variable `var x` in your function and thus overwrite the outer variable `x`.

Comment: We don't need **yet another** answer to this question.